# Not able to send https SMS Android Marshmallow Nexus 6p

Tags: android, sms, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a code to send an SMS.

```
public void sendInvite(ContactRow c) {
    String message = "Here's the link: https://goo.gl/i5dLLe";
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", c.getPhoneNo(), null));
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    startActivityForResult(sendIntent, Statics.REQ_CODE_SMS_INVITE);
}
```

This returns an error code `21` on Nexus 6P running Marshmallow, but works perfectly on non-Marshmallow devices. But, if I change the `https` to `http` in the link in the SMS, the SMS gets sent. Is there a new permission to send `https` links through SMS on marshmallow. Why is this issue happening?

Comment: You aren't sending a link.  Well you are, but the SMS doesn't care-  it just sees a text string.  It could be something weird witht he specific SMS app on your phone, but it isn't a general rule for Android.

Comment: have you go through run time permission in marshmallow?

Comment: Yes. I have the permissions. The weird thing is if I convert https to http the sms is sent